# vbulletin - how to wrap the whole thing in my own header and footer?

Tags: php, vbulletin

Is it possible to wrap vbulletin in my own header and footer? What files would I need to edit? I want to put the whole thing inside my site's frame...

Comment: I believe there are specific header.php and footer.php files in the vbulletin structure. You'd have to modify those files.

Comment: I don't think there are such files.

Comment: I have seen all sorts of implementations of this, but the most effective are often those that simply put vbulletin in an iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go to ACP - Styles & Templates - Style Manager - Your Style - Edit templates - header (and footer)